"Strength" of cointegration
In various non-academic articles/posts, I have come across the claim that the magnitude of the first eigenvalue in Johansen's cointegration test for a pair (pairwise test) might indicate the "strength" of cointegration. I searched the entire internet but couldn't find academic references. Could someone elaborate on this topic—either refute or confirm this thesis (fully or partially)?

Cross-posted on Quantitative Finance SE here.

A function of this first eigenvalue is a test statistic for the null of no cointegration, see The eigen values of Johansen's cointegration procedure, viz.
$$
-T\log(1-\hat\lambda_1)
$$
To the extent that a large test statistic can be taken to be "strong" evidence against the null (so for cointegration) the answer would be yes. However, as is typical with hypothesis tests (you will find many hits on this site, such as Why are lower p-values not more evidence against the null? Arguments from Johansson 2011) not clear at all, to say the least: e.g., if the null is false, the size of the test statistic also depends on the sample size, so that comparisons across test statistics with different sample sizes are somewhat difficult.
